# Probability distribution database

Tags: probability, regression, data-analysis

Is there some kind of probability distribution database? Very often I'm faced with a problem of fitting a distribution to data. And it also happens very often that exponential-looking data doesn't fit to exponential distribution. But because my "internal database" of PDFs is not large enough I have to compromise. Is there some place that I can use as a resource to seek for another options? Preferably with suggested methods how to (efficiently) test fit to that distribution.

Comment: Are these not enough? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions, http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm, (see also the references cited in the second link). Also I should play the goodie two shoes here and point out that you shouldn't be choosing your model to fit your data, because that leads to false positives. You should choose a model in advance, and if the model doesn't fit, then you reject your hypothesis. But data-fitting is a big statistical no-no.